# Grails 3.0.x plugin unable to run integration tests with database

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-plugin

When I run

```
grails create-app some-app
```

and

```
grails create-integration-test SomeTest
```

with a really complicated test:

```
expect:
1 == 1
```

It works just fine. Same when I update the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"

    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"

/**/compile  'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41' /**This is new**/

    runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"


    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"

    // Note: It is recommended to update to a more robust driver (Chrome, Firefox etc.)
    testRuntime 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.44.0'

    console "org.grails:grails-console"
}
```

and the application.yml

```
dataSource: &pg_baseline ###Only the datasource is updated###
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    url: jdbc:postgresql://le-server:5432/LeDatabase
    username: ***le superuser***
    password: ***le password***

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            << : *pg_baseline
            url: le-server:5432/LeDatabase_Dev

    test:
        dataSource:
            << : *pg_baseline
            url: le-server:5432/LeDatabase_Test
```

to work with a PostgreSQL test database. However, if I follow the same steps but with create-plugin (--profile=plugin, or web-plugin, or not specified profile). Adding the exact same changes to build.gradle + applicatione.yml for the plugin, then running integration tests yields the sweet sweet message:

```
SomeTest > test something FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExcepti
on
                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

1 test completed, 1 failed
:integrationTest FAILED
```

In all cases, this is using the following command to run the tests:

```
grails test-app -integration --stacktrace
```

Are plugins not able to test against a live database? Do I need some other flag on my test running?

Comment: If you are still interested in solving this question, can you please give es the `application.yml` file you use?